# Piwik Actions.getPageTitles question!

Tags: php, matomo

Hello I'm retrieving pages that are most visited,it works fine,but how can I retrieve also and links to that pages,not just page titles.Any other Action,or similar function?

Thanks!

Comment: Any help with this ? piwik forums don't work :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Actions.getPageUrls report to get all page URLs, but you can't get the list of URLs for a given Title. See http://dev.piwik.org/trac/wiki/API/Reference
Example of Actions.getPageUrls call: http://demo.piwik.org/?module=API&method=Actions.getPageUrls&idSite=1&period=day&date=today&format=xml&token_auth=anonymous